# How to display video on emulator in android

Tags: android, video, android-emulator

I have a question that How can we play video in android emulator because when we want to play the same it doesn't display on the android emulator, we don't know why? Please suggest me for the right answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try it android>=2.1 emulator,i thinks it works fine

Answer (score 2):

The emulator doesn't work here because its space is less and its resolution is not good. Try it on the actual, real Android device.

I (serzila10) faced the same problem using 5554 emulator, with Android 2.1, and this was the (unfortunate) way I solved it.